# How do I programmatically create a file and write it in the private:// folder?

Tags: 8, files

How do I programmatically create a text file and write to it in the private:// folder in **Drupal 8.8?** I found some examples, but all of them use deprecated functions and they don't work.

Here what I have now, but i't s not creating folder and text file in it with content:

```
use Drupal\Core\StreamWrapper\PrivateStream;
...
...
$output = 'Test Text';
$file_save_path_stream_directory =  'private://gmt';

file_prepare_directory($file_save_path_stream_directory, FILE_CREATE_DIRECTORY | FILE_MODIFY_PERMISSIONS);

$fileLocation = $file_save_path_stream_directory . '/test.txt';

$file = file_save_data($output, $fileLocation, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
```

Comment: What is `$file` after the call? Have you checked the function docs to see what that would suggest?

Comment: You want to be looking at using Filesystem. Your going to want to look at the 8.8 documentation pages for those deprecated functions, they link off to the new Filesystem methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone need it, I make it work:

```
use Drupal\Core\File\FileSystemInterface;

...

  /**
   * @var \Drupal\Core\File\FileSystemInterface
   */
  protected $fileSystem;


  public function __construct(FileSystemInterface $fileSystem) {
    $this->fileSystem = $fileSystem;
  }

  public function testCreation() {
    $request = 'test content';
    $path = 'private://gmt/';
    if ($this->fileSystem->prepareDirectory($path, FileSystemInterface::CREATE_DIRECTORY)) {
      /** @var \Drupal\file\FileInterface $file */
      $file = file_save_data(
        $request,
        $path . 'requests.txt'
      );
    }
  }
```

Comment: `file_save_data()` is deprecated in Drupal 9.3 and will be removed in Drupal 10.

Comment: way to give credit to the answerer...  not.

Comment: @eric Answers that are outdated and no longer work don't need more credit unless the answer is updated. Answers that remain relevant should move to the top with upvotes.

Comment: When putting this in an action plugin I'm getting error `TypeError: Drupal\test\Plugin\Action\GenerateQrImage::__construct(): Argument #1 ($file_system) must be of type Drupal\Core\File\FileSystemInterface, array given`

Answer (score 5):

This answer is tested with Drupal 9.3 and doesn't use `file_save_data()`, which is deprecated in 9.3 and will be removed in Drupal 10.

```php
use Drupal\Core\File\FileSystemInterface;

...

  /**
   * Provides helpers to operate on files and stream wrappers.
   *
   * @var \Drupal\Core\File\FileSystemInterface
   */
  protected $fileSystem;

  /**
   * Constructs an object.
   *
   * @param \Drupal\Core\File\FileSystemInterface $file_system
   *   The file system manager.
   */
  public function __construct(FileSystemInterface $file_system) {
    $this->fileSystem = $file_system;
  }

  public function testFunction($data, $destination) {
    if (!$this->fileSystem->prepareDirectory($destination, FileSystemInterface::CREATE_DIRECTORY)) {
      // @todo Log an error.
      return FALSE;
    }

    $this->fileSystem->saveData($data, $destination, FileSystemInterface::EXISTS_REPLACE);

    // Create and save a new file entity.
    // @see FileRepository::createOrUpdate().
    $new_file = File::create(['uri' => $file->uri]);
    $new_file->setOwnerId(1);
    $new_file->setPermanent();
    $new_file->save();

    return $new_file;
  }
```

It should also be noted that in Drupal 9.3, though `$data` can be a file handle `resource` passed to `fileSystem->saveData()`, it is not documented and doesn't have test coverage. `file_save_data()` also allowed a `resource` data parameter. `FileRepository::writeData()` does not allow one, however, although that's only because it specifies `string $data` in the function declaration.

Comment: Undefined variable '$file', while '$data' is unused.. are they the same variable?

Comment: Also `Argument #1 ($file_system) must be of type Drupal\Core\File\FileSystemInterface, array given`

Comment: @kopeboy Firstly, this isn't an action. Second, this is not a complete example. You need to write your own code rather than expecting it to work with just copy and paste. `$file` could be a Drupal file entity. `$data` is whatever data you pass to the function. And if you're getting an error, it's because you're passing an array instead of a FileSystem, just like the error says. It's not a bug in my code, but in yours.

Comment: @kopeboy If you're writing an action plugin, fine, but you will still need to inject the `FileSystem`, and you'll still need to call `File::create()`, etc.