# Create a PDF from a node after the node is deleted

Tags: nodes

I want to create a PDF from a node when the node is deleted.

I am rendering the node using the following code.

```php
$entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager();
$view_builder = $entity->getViewBuilder('node');
$build = $view_builder->view($node);
$output = \Drupal::service('renderer')->render($build);
```

The output comes from node.html.twig, whereas the actual template file should be node--content-type--full.html.twig.

I am using the `Dompdf\Dompdf` class to create and store the PDF file.

```php
$options = new Options();
$options->setIsHtml5ParserEnabled(true);
$options->set('isRemoteEnabled', TRUE);
$dompdf = new Dompdf($options);
$dompdf->load_html($node_html);
$dompdf->set_paper('A4', 'portrait');
$dompdf->render();
```

How do I get the exact design of the node?

Comment: `$build = $view_builder->view($node, 'full');` to render the Full content view mode.

Comment: When you delete the node, what theme is active? Is is the same one with your overridden template file?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! Which hook are you using to render a node after it has been deleted? As @Clive said, probably Drupal is using the administrative theme for the confirmation page;  that's why the template file is not the expected one.

Comment: $build = $view_builder->view($node, 'full'); this doesn't work. It's the same result

Comment: I am using hook_node_delete.

Comment: After you create the pdf (render()), you will need to get the name and save the file to a directory correct? This post might help: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/309049/8667